# print and sort a list of class in oop python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a class name Student like this:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name = '', age = 0, test_score = 0):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.test_Scores = test_score
    def __str__(self):
        return "({0},{1},{2})".format(self.name,self.age, self.test_Scores)
```

and  class name Students:

```
class Students():
    stds = list()
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass
    def Input(self):
        while True:
            inputName = input('Enter name: ')
            inputAge = int(input('Enter age: '))
            inputTestScore = int(input('Enter test score: '))
            std = Student(inputName, inputAge, inputTestScore)
            if inputAge == 0:
                break
            self.stds.append(std)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.stds)
```

Here are some code print out a list of students:

```
stds = Students()
stds.Input()
print(stds)
```

With 2 elements in the list, the result after excute look like this:
[<**main**.Student object at 0x0000026EDEBC5FA0>, <**main**.Student object at 0x0000026EDEBC5CD0>]

I can't print out `stds` under a string, how can i fix it. And how to sort `stds` by the decreasing of age ?
Pls help me !

Comment: You must retrieve the string presentation of each student in the list individually in a loop and combine it to string of all of them.

Comment: You print the representation of the `Student` instances so you should define `__repr__` for `Student` e.g. `return f'Student(name={self.name}, age={self.age}, test_score={self.test_Scores})'`. But there are many flaws in your code. Why is the naming so strange. Why is `stds` an attribute of the `Students` class and not of the instance? ...

Comment: for now u can change in students class like this :    
 def __str__(self):
        return str([s.__dict__ for s in self.stds])

Comment: A list has a "sort" method which has a "key" parameter. This key is a function which should return the age for a given student.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write the function str for students class.

```
def __str__(self):
   return '\n'.join(self.stds)
```

Comment: Careful! `.__str__` should not call `print`!! It should return a string. Try something like `return '\n'.join(self.stds)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have class `Students`, you should have a list of `Student`. To get the data from the class variables override the `__repr__` method. To sort the list you can use `lambda` with the attribute to sort by as key in `sort()` function

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name='', age=0, test_score=0):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.test_Scores = test_score

    def __repr__(self):
        return "({0},{1},{2})".format(self.name, self.age, self.test_Scores)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    stds = list()
    while True:
        inputName = input('Enter name: ')
        inputAge = int(input('Enter age: '))
        inputTestScore = int(input('Enter test score: '))
        std = Student(inputName, inputAge, inputTestScore)
        if inputAge == 0:
            break
        stds.append(std)
    stds.sort(key=lambda s: s.name)
    print(stds)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this =>

```
class Student:
def __init__(self, name = '', age = 0, test_score = 0):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
    self.test_Scores = test_score
def __str__(self):
    return "({0},{1},{2})".format(self.name,self.age, self.test_Scores)
def __repr__(self):
    return "({0},{1},{2})".format(self.name,self.age, self.test_Scores)

def __lt__(self, other):
     return self.age < other.age
    
class Students():
    stds = list()
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass
    def Input(self):
        while True:
            inputName = input('Enter name: ')
            inputAge = int(input('Enter age: '))
            inputTestScore = int(input('Enter test score: '))
            std = Student(inputName, inputAge, inputTestScore)
            if inputAge == 0:
                break
            self.stds.append(std)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.stds)

stds = Students()
stds.Input()
print(stds)
stds.stds.sort(reverse=True)
print(stds)
```

Comment: You should keep in mind that the documentation for [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) says: "If at all possible, this should look like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same value (given an appropriate environment)."

Comment: Also, I remember reading in some documentation somewhere that for both `.__str__` and `.__repr__`, in the case of a container or nested object, the inner objects should be represented with their `repr` form. So at the very least it should be `return "({0},{1},{2})".format(repr(self.name),repr(self.age), repr(self.test_Scores))`

Answer (score 0):

Define a *natural order* for the students based on their age using `@functools.total_ordering`:

```py
import functools


@functools.total_ordering
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name='', age=0, test_score=0):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.test_Scores = test_score

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.age < other.age

    def __str__(self):
        return "({0},{1},{2})".format(self.name, self.age, self.test_Scores)


def test_sorting_students():
    alice: Student = Student("Alice", 21, 86)
    bob: Student = Student("Bob", 19, 75)
    caroline: Student = Student("Caroline", 20, 93)

    students = [alice, bob, caroline]
    students.sort()

    assert students[0] == bob
    assert students[1] == caroline
    assert students[2] == alice
```

Then just sort them:

```py
print(stds.sort())
```